# Como inserir o valor da PK de uma tabela na FK de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Criei uma tabela `usuario` usando:

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
    usuario_id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nome varchar(200));
```

Então outra tabela usando:

```
CREATE TABLE image(
    id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    nome varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    id_user int,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES usuario(usuario_id) ON CASCADE);
```

Essa é minha estrutura para quando um usuário fizer upload de uma imagem a tabela `image` além de receber um novo `id` e o endereço da imagem no campo `nome`, ela receba também o `id` do usuário que fez a ação. Porém não acontece nada. O campo `id_user` fica nulo.

Até onde eu entendi é preciso que ao inserir uma imagem o campo `id_user` receba o valor de `usuario_id` automaticamente, ouvi falar dos triggers mas não estou conseguindo implementar isso no código.

Código que faz a inserção na tabela image:

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

if(empty($_FILES['arquivo']['name'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}


$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$_FILES['arquivo']['name'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO image(nome) VALUES('{$uploadfile}')";
if(mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
        header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else {
            echo "Falied to send!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Na pergunta você mostrou a estrutura das duas tabelas, mas qual foi o código que você escreveu para fazer essas inserções de registros? Sem ele não tem como saber o que está errado. E qual é banco de dados que você está usando?

Comment: Vou colocar na pergunta.

Comment: Se "ouviu falar de triggers", mas não sabe implementar. Nada adianta pedir ajuda aqui pois ninguém vai fazer o código pra você e ensinar é algo que por aqui dificilmente ajuda. Essa comunidade tem único foco de ajudar a resolver problemas através da troca de informações. Aparentemente seu banco é Mysql e a um erro na sintase na declaração da FOREIGN KEY conforme esse conteúdo https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Leia esse artigo sobre triggers, talvez lhe ajude a entender o conceito https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-triggers/8088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de se inserir, e você pode inserir manualmente. Se o usuário estiver logado, na autenticação do login, se bem sucedido, pode declarar uma `$_SESSION['id']`.

O insert ficaria:

```
INSERT INTO image(nome, id_user) VALUES('{$uploadfile}', '$_SESSION[id]')
```